# Having trouble getting a php rotating script to work

Tags: php

first off, sorry if this question is very basic/redundant.  I have no php experience and next to no programming experience.

Basically, what I am trying to do is utilize a rotating script that is provided here:

http://www.jim.am/rotating-offer-pages-and-landing-pages-in-prosper202/

I followed the instructions on the site, they're really quite simple - as all I need to do is switch out his links for mine.

However when I click my "rotate.php?kw=" link it just goes to the page which is obviously just a blank white page.  It seems the rotating script is not working for some reason.

So I'm just hoping someone more familiar with php could give a glance over the code (its in the link posted above).  Its just 15 lines of code btw...

Thanks!

edit:

here is the link to my attempt at the rotation:

http://test.p2track.com/rotate.php?kw=test123

my code is below:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['kw']) {
$kw = strip_tags($_GET['kw']);
} else { $kw = ‘jimrocks’; }
$landingpages = array(
// paste as many tracking links as you like below
// copy and paste the whole line and put the link between the ‘ and the ‘
‘http://be2canada.struenet.com/RuleLP/?t202id=3109&t202kw=’.$kw,
‘http://be2canada.struenet.com/RegLP/?t202id=8115&t202kw='.$kw,
);
$searchlink = $landingpages[array_rand($landingpages)];
header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”);
header(“Location: $searchlink”);
exit();
?>
```

OK - my new code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['kw']) {
$kw = strip_tags($_GET['kw']);
} else { $kw = ‘jimrocks’; }
$landingpages = array(
// paste as many tracking links as you like below
// copy and paste the whole line and put the link between the ‘ and the ‘
'http://be2canada.struenet.com/RuleLP/?t202id=3109&t202kw='.$kw,
'http://be2canada.struenet.com/RegLP/?t202id=8115&t202kw='.$kw,
);
$searchlink = $landingpages[array_rand($landingpages)];
header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”);
header(“Location: $searchlink”);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: The link goes to the blog post, not your code.

Comment: Please post your code and error messages (if any). without that we cannot know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: OK - here is my code:  edit: its really hard to format it properly... ill try to edit my OP

Comment: Looks to be an issue with your single and double quotes. If you've copy-pasted the code from the blog where you found it that is likely to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Must be a syntax error in the php code somewhere.

Add this at the top of your php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Than please provide any error messages (if there are any)

EDIT: Right, you have a syntax error in your links:

```
‘http://be2canada.struenet.com/RuleLP/?t202id=3109&t202kw=’.$kw,
‘http://be2canada.struenet.com/RegLP/?t202id=8115&t202kw='.$kw,
```

change this apostrophe ‘ to this: '

```
'http://be2canada.struenet.com/RuleLP/?t202id=3109&t202kw='.$kw,
'http://be2canada.struenet.com/RegLP/?t202id=8115&t202kw='.$kw,
```

also change this double-quotes ” to this: "

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $searchlink");
```

Even stackoverflow's code-highlighter detected it

Comment: What if it gives an error message and the author is able to fix it by himself/herself?

Comment: i've edited the code, and it still doesn't seem to work - I'll post how my new code looks in the OP.

Comment: There's also an issue with the double-quotes. Please see above

Answer (score 0):

Change `‘’` and `“”` To `''` or `""` accordingly.

Looks like a code copy paste from somewhere.